# OpenLayers 3 & Ionic 2, not displayed after loading

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, openlayers-3, ionic2, display

I followed the solution of this topic ([Ionic 2 Beta and Open Layers 3 not loading map 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36152343/ionic-2-beta-and-open-layers-3-not-loading-map/38633579)) in order to integrate OL3 into an Ionic 2 app, but I have an issue. When I serve, the map load but it's visually empty. I have to resize my browser to make it appear. So I imagine it's a refresh problem...
I'm new with Ionic and Angular, so here I am :). Do you have any clue ? Thanks !

map.component.ts

```
import {Component, ViewChild, Renderer} from '@angular/core';
declare var ol: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'olmap',
  template: '<div id="map" #map class="full-map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>'
})
export class OLMap {
  @ViewChild('map') map;
  constructor(public renderer: Renderer) {
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
     var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      });
      var london = ol.proj.transform([-0.12755, 51.507222], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
      var view = new ol.View({
        center: london,
        zoom: 6
      });
      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [layer],
        view: view
      });
  }
}
```

home.ts

```
import {Page}   from 'ionic-angular';
import {OLMap} from './component/map.component';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html',
  directives: [OLMap]
})

export class HomePage {
    constructor() {

    }
}
```

home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Test
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <olmap></olmap>
</ion-content>
```

And on my index.html

```
<script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.17.1/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="https://openlayersbook.github.io/openlayers_book_samples/assets/ol3/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link type="text/css" href="https://openlayersbook.github.io/openlayers_book_samples/assets/css/samples.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Could you give us more details about your code? Thanks!

Comment: Sure @ThierryTemplier ! Done.

Comment: @ThierryTemplier I added setTimeout(function(){window.dispatchEvent(new Event("resize"));}, 100); at the end of ngAfterViewInit(). But I imagine it's a bit dirty... And It doesn't work on mobile  (IonicView) !

Answer (score 0):

I guess that it's a problem of change detection. Perhaps you could leverage the `detectChanges` method of the `ChangeDetectorRef` class.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'olmap',
  template: '<div id="map" #map class="full-map" data-tap-disabled="true"></div>'
})
export class OLMap {
  @ViewChild('map') map;
  constructor(public renderer: Renderer, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { // <-----
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
     var layer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
     });
     var london = ol.proj.transform([-0.12755, 51.507222], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
     var view = new ol.View({
       center: london,
       zoom: 6
     });
     var map = new ol.Map({
       target: 'map',
       layers: [layer],
       view: view
     });
     this.cdr.detectChanges(); // <-----
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but nope it doesn't work. I still need to resize manually. Even if try in home.ts.

Comment: Actually, if I mix with a setTimeout it works...! 
setTimeout(function(){
        window.dispatchEvent(new Event("resize"));
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
      }, 200); Is it a real solution ? @ThierryTemplier

Comment: Hi @Xav, could you please explain your solution with cdr.detectChanges()?
I'm using it after the map creation but it doesn't seem to work

        setTimeout(
          ()=>{
            window.dispatchEvent(new Event("resize"));
            this.cdr.detectChanges();
          }, 2000,this);

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's the OL3 map that needs update to be displayed, try adding :

```
map.updateSize();
```

after creating your map

Comment: Hi @Hicham ! Nope it changes nothing sorry. When I hit the button Zoom In, Zoom Out or North Direction, it changes nothing as well. So I'm not sure interacting with the map do something.